# Elasticsearch DNS Host Setup in a cluster

Tags: elasticsearch, dns, cluster-computing, distributed-computing

I have been asked to take care of  an ES cluster with 14 machines.

For example:
Hostnames of my machines start with **es1.abc.com** till **es14.abc.com**
These all are part of a cluster called ***"es-test"*** configured in elasticsearch.yml

Now suppose the DNS A record  of this cluster  is **es.abc.com**.

The current DNS resolves es.abc.com to 4 machines es1.abc.com to es4.abc.com in a round robin set up. So all the HTTP requests hit these 4 machines first.

The only difference I see is that these 4 machines having SSD and other 10 machines have hard disks

I do not have any idea why the original engineer set up like this.

In ES documentation , I could not find any particular mention of DNS resolution guidelines.

I do not see a reason why I can not set up DNS resolution to all 14 machines.

I am not an expert in ES. If I have missed something obvious pleaase point me to the right documentation. 
Your help would be truly appreciated

Comment: I'm scratching my head with the same question. Did you ever figure this out?